# Push update to different user

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to understand how to do the following:

I have a dashboard that is used by two different user types. 
One user takes an action and I update my db with submitted data using .ajax() post on a separate page. After the data is stored I return response and update this user's view with jQuery.

Now, the other user, who this data is relevant to has a portal open as well -- how do I update his view without constantly refreshing his page?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this without refreshing his page would be to query the server via ajax at a given interval and re-render only the data display if needed.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger this query after I make an insert from the first user? Because I don't know how often the posts will be made.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this via ajax, no. If your project is small enough and you have a small number of clients, you can use web sockets, as the other answer suggests.

Comment: I probably don't need a constant connection to the server. I'd be happy if it was triggered when a db update happens. I'm gonna try and poke around looking fr similar cases.

Comment: Why don't you use a time-based trigger? Place a timer that fires a request (say, every 500ms) to your server via ajax, then update _if_ there are any changes.

Comment: An even better solution would be to use xhr-long-polling. As far as I can tell that's the best solution besides sockets. But that does require some wizardry to set up, I think. Facebook uses it for its chat system, so it must be a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

If you need realtime information, you should consider using socket connections. For such a small project, you should check out [pusher.com](https://pusher.com/) and sign up for their free plan. Then all you need to do is include the pusher js file and subscribe both users to the same channel. They have great documentation and examples.

Then on the backend, you could fire off an event every time a user makes a change which would alert the other user of the changes. By the way, this is how a chat system works.

Comment: I'd like to have it hosted on my site, if possible. I don't know how many users will be using it at the moment. Are there libraries for this functionality using websockets. I found some resources but they seem a bit dated.

Comment: If you need to make your own "pusher.com" server, you should check out node.js and socket.io. Here is a link to a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QISU14OrRbI